# WebView instruction sequence is sometimes not in expected order

Tags: android, browser, webview, spinner, sequence

I am trying to keep a spinner item updated based upon the currently displayed page in my web browser.  I'm having a problem when I hit the back button in that the url returned from getUrl() AFTER the goBack function is returning the PREVIOUS, and not the updated URL.  The browser updates as expected, I'm just getting an outdated value for my url variable.  I'm assuming I'm seeing an issue associated with multiple threads.  Can anyone tell mw how to ensure that my goBack() and getUrl() instructions to work in the expected sequence?
Thanks!

```
    Button back_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back_button);
    back_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public synchronized void onClick(View view) {
            if (browser.canGoBack())
                browser.goBack();
                String url = browser.getUrl();
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Browser URL = " + url);
                setDocSpinner(doc_spinner, url);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider doing this from a [`WebViewClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) instead of from the back button's listener. Overriding [`onPageStarted`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageStarted%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String,%20android.graphics.Bitmap%29) and [`onPageFinished`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) could be particularly useful.

Comment: Thanks!  Sounds like just the ticket.  I'll give it a try.